# Average of values in an array

Tags: r, sequence, moving-average

I have  an array and want to build a loop which averages every second value starting at the first value of the array and after the first round the loop should start with the second value of the array.

For example:

```
3,6,18,10,2
```

The result should be:

```
7.666,8,10

   for 7.6666= (3+18+2)/3 
   for 8= (6+10)/2
   for 10=(18+2)/2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) could be useful for you to improve your question

Comment: Are you sure your answer to `(3+18+2)/3` is correct?

Comment: @mnel, I am pretty sure it's not. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
x <- c(3,6,18,10,2)

n <- length(x)
sapply(seq_len(n-2), function(X) {
    mean(x[seq(X, n, by=2)])
})
# [1]  7.666667  8.000000 10.000000
```

---

And then something more interesting, to *earn* @mnel's upvote ;)

```
n <- length(x)
m <- matrix(0, n, n-2)
ii <- row(m) - col(m)
m[ii >= 0 & !ii %% 2] <- 1
colSums(x * m)/colSums(m)
# [1]  7.666667  8.000000 10.000000
```

Comment: Too quick. I shouldn't have spent time alerting the OP to their basic arithmetic error.

Comment: @mnel -- I did treat this one as basically a speed typing test. Maybe I'll see if I can come up with something more elegant/interesting.

Answer (score 5):

Another one for the lovers:

```
rev(filter(rev(x), 0:1, "r") / filter(rep(1, length(x)), 0:1, "r"))
# [1]  7.666667  8.000000 10.000000 10.000000  2.000000
```

Comment: `filter` always seems like voodoo to me and the help file goes over my head. Is there a `filter() for dummies` available?

Comment: @thelatemail, I have the same problem. And extra-points for explanations about how to think about `Reduce` and `Filter`. I occasionally get them to work, but I fell flat on my face when trying it on this one. Post a question. I'll vote for it.